# Apache rewrite configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

Can someone help me understand what "(?:^|&)" and "(?:&|$)" mean below? I skimmed through the documentation but it is not clear.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)site=(eu|jp|in)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?fetchHomePage.action$ https://example.com/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Leads here is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a non-capturing group? What does (?:) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)

Comment: This is not Apache-specific, but a general regular expression feature - see duplicate for explanation.